# How do I draw arcs using Metal?

Tags: ios, metal

I went through a few tutorials on iOS Metal API and they mention that everything in Metal is a triangle.In that case, if I want to draw an arc, will I have to import core graphics and use it or is there a way to do it using Metal?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to create hundreds or possibly thousands of triangles and fit them together like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iai86.png. That is how GPU hardware works at a low level — a triangle is the only shape they are able to draw.

Comment: "Everything" is not accurate. Obviously, for example, every texture ever painted does not depict a triangle. Also, please define "draw".

Comment: I meant whatever you wish to render/display on the screen must be decomposed into triangles.

Comment: You are going to need some math start now :))

Answer (score 6):

GPUs (with some rare exceptions) work exclusively with triangles. A square is just two triangles butted up against each other. A circle is just a group of tiny triangles arranged in a fan shape. Every shape is made up of lots of small triangles in the appropriate pattern.

Metal is communicating with the GPU in a low level way, so now it becomes your job to express shapes in terms of groups of triangles.